# tcsh random number from /dev/random and /dev/urandom

Tags: random, tcsh

I am trying to figure out how to generate random from using /dev/random and /dev/urandom in tcsh. After I do head -c 1 /dev/random, I get a random byte. How do I turn this byte into actual number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ head -c 1 /dev/urandom | od -t u1 | cut -c9-
```

That will give you a random integer between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Answer (score 7):

My apologies for redirecting your question in advance but despite not using it for your script, bash can be handy here if you have it:

```
bash -c 'echo $RANDOM'
```

will return a random integer.  You can use therefore:

```
RANDOM=`bash -c 'echo $RANDOM'`
```

from within a tcsh script to achieve the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

this works in csh OS X -> generate 1 number between 2 and 10 and assign it to random:

```
set random = `jot -r 1 2 10`
echo "random number $random was generated"
```